# Tomcat Maven Plugin - A child container failed during start

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm developping a multi-module maven project and I want to run my web project in Tomcat7 but i have this error "A child container failed during start".

I proceeded : (right click on the web project)-> run as -> run configuration -> goal : tomcat7:run   , and I have this log :

> avr. 15, 2014 5:39:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>   SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       ... 7 more

First this is my parent pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/ -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<modules>
    <module>../release-management-core</module>
    <module>../release-management-common</module>
    <module>../release-management-web</module>
</modules>
```

This is the pom.xml of the web project:

```
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ott.release.management</groupId>
        <artifactId>release-management-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- SPRING WEB -->
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- PrimeFaces 4.0 -->
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- optional theme (see also web.xml to enable it) -->
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bluesky</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces-themes.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces-extension.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>releaseManagement</finalName>
    <plugins>


    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.2</version>

            <configuration>
                <port>8082</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

This my web.xml:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Parser fichier JSF -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Lier JSF et Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Context needed when adding el-impl for Tomcat 6 -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <description>Primefaces theme</description>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:context/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please, I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```